# Should send null or empty string value via body?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, restful-url

Should we send a null or empty string value on request ?

I mean we have an optional value and it had a value currently. If use want to delete value of that optional field, should API understand null or empty is delete value ?

Ex:

```
{
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  phone: { type: String, required: false }
}
```

In database:

```
{
  name: "Alex",
  phone: "012-333.222"
}
```

And now, use want to delete their phone number
Should we define looks like:

```
PUT /users/user-id-1
{
  phone: null
}
```

Seems it's a bad convention

Comment: You can do whatever you want. Probably just send `null`.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković just saying something but don't explain why, for me is personal answer without fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should we send a null or empty string value on request ?

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care; which is to say that it tells us to use self descriptive messages to [transfer documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s), but it doesn't tell us what the representations of the documents should be.

Where you want to be looking instead is at message schema definitions, and in particular designing your schema in such a way that it can be extended in backwards compatible ways.  The XML community spent a lot of time exploring those ideas; [Orchard 2004](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/10/27/extend.html) might be a good starting point.

---

In HTTP, the basic mechanism for describing a change to a resource is to use a PUT command with a copy of the new representation.  So a request would probably look like:

```
PUT /users/user-id-1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  name: "Alex",
  phone: null
}
```

If your schema is defined in such a way that the `phone` field is optional, and that optional and null are equivalent (as opposed to some other implied value), then you might equivalently use:

```
PUT /users/user-id-1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  name: "Alex"
}
```

In cases where the representation is very big, and the changes you are making are small, you might want to support PATCH.

```
PATCH /users/user-id-1
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json

{
  phone: null
}
```

Note that the [HTTP PATCH](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5789) specification includes the [Allow-Patch](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5789#section-3.1) which allows clients to discover which patch representations a server supports for a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Though, in front end, usually it depends on whether use the delete button or, they just leave the field empty

`phone: ''` - means user left field empty

`phone: null` - means user click on delete field button. You decide whether to delete the field, or just set the document field to null.

I will usually delete the field, since it is now useless.

Comment: but I alway use DELETE method to delete an user, If user request DELETE /user/user-id-1, API will delete user with userId = user-id-1 in database

Comment: in your case you are right. In my api, when i delete a user, i always add parameter as confirmation code. Updated the answer with my views.

Comment: I don't want to save null value to database, I will delete the field, but don't have delete button on UI, user will delete value in phone textbox and click the Update button. Front-end send { phone: "" } or { phone: null } and I don't like this, so I need a new defination for this case. Because front-end always send null if textbox is empty, if UI have a lot of textboxes, API receive a lot of null value and have to meny checks

Comment: In that case user should `PUT { name: 'Name', phone: 'Phone', email: 'Email' }` them you just update the entire sub document. And you update as it is.

Comment: ? I not really understand. How about case user delete phone value ? I don't want to update entire document, I just want to update some fields that use really wants update

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update only one property in a document you can use PATCH method instead of PUT method and your code should look like this:

```
PATCH /users/user-id-1
{
     phone: ""
}
```